# Drupal View rewriting output of the field

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I created a taxonomy vocabulary with several terms and it is assigned to a content type. So a node can have multiple terms from that vocabulary. After assigning it I have created a view to format the content type nodes into a json data.

Now in the JSON data the taxonomy field is showing multiple values. I want to separate those individual items by comma. Please help me out how to do it. I've tried adding this expression to the tpl file.

`]+>/i', ', ', $output); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your view, it is difficult to solve. But if you edit the taxonomy field in your view, make sure that in the `MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS` section the checkbox "Display all values in the same row" is checked. That should display the taxonomy terms as `term 1, term 2, term n`.